# Turbine can only find one host when using docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, turbine, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-stream

I have 3 projects: A hystrix dashboard, a turbine server (using AMQP) and an API

When I start in development env, I set up 2 instances of the API (using port 8080 and 8081). To test the turbine aggregation, I make calls and in the dashboard, I can see `Hosts: 2`.
Although when I use Docker, even when the load balancer hits the 2 server, I only see one Host on the hystrix dashboard.

My assumptions:
1- as both containers start on the same port (8080), Turbine sees them as one
2- as I also dockerize RabbitMQ, this may be causing problems

here is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '2'
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:9.5
        ports:
          - "5432"
        environment:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_DB: fq
        volumes:
          - /var/lib/postgresql

      rabbitmq:
        image: rabbitmq:3-management
        ports:
          - "5672"
          - "15672"
        environment:
          RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: turbine
          RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: turbine
        volumes:
          - /var/lib/rabbitmq/

      hystrix:
        build: hystrixdashboard/.
        links:
          - turbine_server
        ports:
          - "8989:8989"

      turbine_server:
        build: turbine/.
        links:
          - rabbitmq
        ports:
          - "8090:8090"

      persona_api:
        build: persona/.
        ports:
          - "8080"
        links:
          - postgres
          - rabbitmq

      lb:
        image: 'dockercloud/haproxy:1.5.1'
        links:
          - persona_api
        volumes:
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        ports:
          - 80:80
```

my `persona_api` config file

```
 spring:
  application:
    name: persona_api
  profiles:
    active: dev
  rabbitmq:
    addresses: 127.0.0.1:5672
    username: turbine
    password: turbine
    useSSL: false

server:
  compression.enabled: true
  port: ${PORT:8080}

params:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
    maximumPoolSize: 10
    poolName: fq_connection_pool

spring.jpa:
  show-sql: true
  hibernate:
    ddl-auto: update

turbine:
  aggregator:
    clusterConfig: persona_api
  appConfig: persona_api

---

spring:
  profiles: dev

params:
  datasource:
    jdbcUrl: jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/fq
---

spring:
  profiles: docker
  rabbitmq:
    addresses: rabbitmq:5672

params:
  datasource:
    jdbcUrl: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/fq
```

I'm afraid that if I deploy it to production (on Rancher or Docker cloud), I'll see the same problem.

here is a GIF of what is happening when I set up two APIs load balanced

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
hystrix.stream.queue.send-id=false
```

in your API

Answer (score 0):

I do assume your problem is the RabbitMQ connection you are using. Cause the connection string you are using is localhost but actually except the RabbitMQ container on none the connection will be available on localhost. I do suggest that you inject the Rabbit host into your Spring connection using environment variables. If I read your files correct it should be `${RABBITMQ_PORT_5672_TCP_ADDR}` instead of localhost. But be aware that I couldn't try. Its just an educated guess. Better you double check by doing an `env` inside your persona_api container when everything is running.

Comment: I may have missed the whole config: actually, in the application.yml I do have an entry for dockerized rabbitmq using the spring profile "docker" and my persona_api's entrypoint is `ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-Dspring.profiles.active=docker","-jar","/app.jar"]` so I'm pointing to the right address...I

Comment: Ahh sorry, the config was cut off. Can you check if Rabbit sees all the clients just to identify if the issue is with connecting or just reporting.

Comment: I'm using the same username for all the connections (`turbine`) and I can see 3 connections on RabbitMQ but the channels seems weird, I think: https://i.imgur.com/4WmeW11.png shouldn't I see only one channel? and they share this channel, all servers? for the queues, I have only one: springCloudHystrixStream.xxxxxx

Comment: Indeed this looks strange. But what worries me more is that only one connection is active and the others are idling. Did you check that your LB mechanisms are working correctly? I had a similar issue with classic Turbine cause no traffic means no `hystrix.stream`.

Comment: those idle connections I would guess thats normal...no traffic, connection goes idle. I also betting on the LB...I'll check and let you know

Comment: Ok, seems like the problem is not LB related, but somehow rabbitmq related. I was taking a second look, and as the gif show, seems like the rabbitmq is alternating between different channels (even though I can only see one)

Answer (score 0):

It's should be fixed your issue.

> ```
> eureka:
>   instance:
>     prefer-ip-address: true
>     instance-id: ${spring.cloud.client.ipAddress}:${server.port}  #make the application unique on the rancher service layer
> spring:
>   application:
>     index: ${random.uuid} #make the application unique on the rancher containe layer,same service but with multi-instances.
> ```
>
> https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/740

Need instance-id:${spring.cloud.client.ipAddress}:${server.port} and index: ${random.uuid} both